# Running time of sparse matrix multiplication

Tags: complexity-theory, matrices, linear-algebra, numerical-algorithms, sparse-matrices

Given a sparse matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ with $n \ll m$ and $\mathsf{nnz}$ being the number of non-zero-components. What is the running time of computing $M M^T$?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't make any sense. It doesn't make sense to ask for the running time of a computation, unless you specify an algorithm for that computation. So *how* would you calculate this product? That's the first thing you need to do: Specify an algorithm how you calculate the product.

The next step: Assuming that many array elements are zero, can you reduce the amount of work that this algorithm would be doing? For example, if you know that x = 0, then it's pointless to multiply x*y because you know the result is 0. And it's pointless to add x*y to z, because that doesn't change z. So how can you take advantage of many array elements being zero? What's the runtime if you do that?

The next step: Assuming that many array elements are zero, can you reduct the amount of work further? Would you need some clever data structures? If yes, which ones?